Enhancing JavaScript Enum Implementation with Autocomplete Support
Problem:
I am unable to achieve full autocomplete support for custom enum implementation in vanilla JavaScript
/**
 * This doesn't work
 * @template T
 * @param {T} arr
 * @returns {Enum<T>}
 */
export function _enum(...arr) {/* ... */}

const a = _enum({ foo: 0, bar: 1, baz: 2 }); 
a. // Autocomplete works
const b = _enum("foo", "bar", "baz"); 
b. // Autocomplete shows nothing

I believe the issue lies in the fact that ...arr is not an array defined with as const, and I'm unsure of how to resolve this.
Progress:
I have developed a vanilla JavaScript enum implementation that supports both an object and multiple strings as parameters:
export function _enum(...arr) {
    return Object.freeze(
        Object.fromEntries(
            arr.length === 1 && typeof arr[0] === "object"
                ? Object.entries(arr[0]).flatMap(([a, b]) => [
                        [a, b],
                        [b, a],
                  ])
                : arr
                        .map(a => [a, enumItem()])
                        .flatMap(([a, b]) => [
                            [a, b],
                            [b, a],
                        ])
        )
    )
}

In addition, I have created a custom enum type in helpers.d.ts:
type Enum<T> = T extends readonly string[]
  ? { [key in T[number]]: number }
  : T[number];

I have tested the Enum type as follows:
let a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"] as const; // JavaScript doesn't have 'as const'
type A = Enum<typeof a>;

let b = [{ foo: 0, bar: 1, baz: 2 }]; // representation of ...arr parameter
type B = Enum<typeof b>;

// Both A and B have the type
// {
//     foo: number;
//     bar: number;
//     baz: number;
// }
// and autocomplete works in both cases

exact source: github
